Enabling and disabling vba activex checkbox
What I am doing is creating a user-entered form where they can request materials.
What I need to do: Enable/Disable checkboxes based on the limitations allowed PER requestor.
Problem: How do I manipulate the VBA checkboxes based on multiple conditions (name, department, category)? I can't just point to a department (because that’s what I have done so far) because under one department there can be multiple requestors, and request types (where I have my checkboxes) vary for each requestor.
[]
What I have done so far: Please don’t judge! Lol, I know what I have done is inefficient, but I thought this would work. Later, I found out that the requests vary PER REQUESTOR and not department.
Private Sub category_Change()
'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
unprotect_sheet

If Sheet1.Range("D9").Value = "HR Department" Then 'D9 is where the department is given

        If [Category] = "Material Master (Product-Related)" Then
                create1.Enabled = True
                update1.Enabled = True
                Delete.Enabled = False
            ElseIf [Category] = "Material Master (Non-product Related)" Then
                create1.Enabled = True
                update1.Enabled = True
                Delete.Enabled = False

            End If
End If

Example of how my master data table looks like:


There's no screenshot?

Hi sorry! Just edited the post now.

What is the naming scheme for your checkboxes (how do you know which checkboxes need to be changed)?  Where are the rules for each person stored?  In the code itself, or (eg) on a worksheet?

Hi Tim! My basis is a master data table on a worksheet. Its listed down in the master data the only appropriate request types limited to the specific requestor.

Please add a screen shot of your master data table

I can't give you the exact data of my table but I have attached it to my question. Thank you!

How are the checkbox names related to the information in your master table?
